# How can I create this struct?

Tags: python, struct, ctypes

I want to create a struct like this:

```
import ctypes

class MyStruct(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [('field1', /* size of 16 bytes */),
                ('field2', /* size of 4 bytes */)
                ('field3', /* size of 8 bytes */)]
```

What is the types that i need to write here for these sizes of fields ? I want the the max size for `field1` will be 16 bytes so the required value will be written there, and all the other bytes will be zeros (if necessary, up to 16 bytes). And in the same way for `field2` and for `field3`.

Comment: How do you want to use this struct?

Comment: @OlvinRoght I then want to use struct.pack for it and write it to a binary file.

Comment: `ctypes.c_char * 16` for example, if you want the equivalent of `char field1[16]` in C.  Best to show what you would do in C for the structure.

Comment: @user20007266, will be good to add actual types of each field

Comment: You don't need `ctypes` to use `struct.pack`.  For example, `struct.pack('>16sLQ',bytes(range(16)),1,5)` would create a `bytes` string with 16 bytes, a 4-byte unsigned integer, and 8-byte unsigned integer.

Comment: @MarkTolonen And if I want the `16-bytes field` will be a number, it's ok to use `string` type for that?

Comment: In addition to @MarkTolonen suggestion. If you want to operate with structure using field names you can declare [`namedtuple()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple): `MyStruct = namedtuple("MyStruct", "field1 field2 field3")`. You can initialize `MyStruct` from unpacked tuple: `MyStruct._make(unpack("<16sIQ", binary_data))`. And you can pack `MyStruct`: `pack("<16sIQ", *my_struct)`.

Comment: There isn't a 16-byte integer, so you'd have to do something like split into two `c_uint64` fields, or use `n.to_bytes(16,'little')` to generate 16 bytes little-endian value of `n`.

Comment: @MarkTolonen, there's `long double` though..

Comment: @MarkTolonen So you can please explain (with code) how I need to define the struct for that? (And let's say for example that the value in this field will be the value 0x100.)

Comment: @OlvinRoght Depends on the OS and not portable.  On Windows, `ctypes.c_longdouble` is size 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ways.  The 16-bit field makes it a bit tricky:

```py
import ctypes

class MyStruct(ctypes.Structure):
    _pack_ = 1
    _fields_ = (('field1', ctypes.c_ubyte * 16), # C char[16] field1
                ('field2', ctypes.c_uint32),     # C uint32_t field2
                ('field3', ctypes.c_uint64))     # C uint64_t field3
    def __init__(self,a,b,c):
        self.field1[:] = a.to_bytes(16,'little') # [:] trick to copy bytes to c_ubyte array
        self.field2 = b
        self.field3 = c

s = MyStruct(0x100, 0x200, 0x300)
print(bytes(s).hex(' '))

with open('out.bin','wb') as f:
    f.write(bytes(s))

# OR

import struct

b = struct.pack('<16sLQ',(0x100).to_bytes(16,'little'),0x200,0x300)
print(b.hex(' '))

with open('out.bin','wb') as f:
    f.write(b)
```

Output:

```
00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 03 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 03 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

Comment: can you explain what is mean `_pack_ = 1` ? in addition, if I want to write it (the struct) to binary file, how can I do it?

Comment: @user20007266 C structures insert padding bytes if members aren't on aligned address boundaries (8-byte integer must start on an 8-byte offset).  `field3` would be at offset 20 which isn't divisible by 8 so 4 bytes of padding would be added between `field2` and `field3` without indicating packing should be as type as possible with `_pack_=1` (default 8).  I'll edit to show writing to a file.

Comment: If I want just to print it to binary file, I also need to add the pads (`_pcak_ = 1`)?

Comment: In addition, what is mean `to_bytes(16,'little')` - what is mean the keyword `little` here? Why we need it here ?

Comment: Mutibyte Integers can be stored in memory two ways.  The four-byte integer 0x12345678 can be stored big-endian, or high byte to low byte in memory (`12 34 56 78`) or little-endian which is low byte to high byte in memory (`78 56 34 12`).  Intel processors use little-endian.  See the documentation for [`int.to_bytes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#int.to_bytes).  Depending on your use case you may want to use `'big'` (or `>` in `struct.pack`).

Comment: Ok, and how is the "`_pack_=1`" reflected in the second way (by struct.pack)?

Comment: @user20007266 `>` (or `<`) don't enforce alignment so are the same as `_pack_=1`.  Read the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#byte-order-size-and-alignment)

Comment: You can explain just how we get the first `00` in the output ? And in addition why we in fact get this output : `00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 | 00 02 00 00 | 00 03 00 00 00 00 00 00` ?

Comment: @user20007266 Experiment!  Try 0x1234 instead of 0x100.  I just explained little-endian.  change it to `>` and `'big'` to see the difference as well.